# Unity вывести переменную на Arduino

Tags: unity3d, arduino

Как передать переменную в ардуино из юнити и вывести переменную как debug.log в юнити?
unity:

```
public class Conclusion : MonoBehaviour {

SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600);

public string g = "10";
private void Start()
{
    port.Open();
}

void sendInfo()
{           
    port.WriteLine(g);
}
}
```

arduino:

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop() {
Serial.print("rr");
}
```

Comment: Вы определитесь: передаете с Unity на Arduino или с Arduino на Unity. Судя по коду, то вы и там, и там только пишете в порт и ничего из него не читаете.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, именно. Unity на Arduino и проблема в том, что я первый раз использую эту библиотеку и не знаю даже как передать переменную.

Comment: Тогда зачем вы в ардуине постоянно пишете в порт? Вот [здесь](https://www.meccanismocomplesso.org/en/arduino-tutorial-serial-data-actuator/) можете почитать как принимать данные с ПК на ардуину.

Comment: @ГеннадийП, мне нужно будет обновлять информацию на количество часто. тестил. спасибо. запишите как ответ

Comment: Интересная идея, для того чтобы полностью насладиться игрой, сделать в ней поддержку пользовательских устройств на ардуинке.

Answer (score 0):

1. Я бы для начала посмотрел, какой порт юзает Arduino IDE - глянь в настройках, мб там у тебя не первый выбран.
2. Возможно у тебя подключены ещё устройства, которые занимают в данный момент этот порт.

Comment: я уже смотрел. com1

Comment: @Des,  а второй вариант смотрел?

Comment: какие могут устройства еще занимать этот порт?